# My files in usb is not recovered after using diskpart and recovery tools

Tags: windows, usb, data-recovery

what should I do to recover all my important files(Word, Excel, pictures) in a usb that has been previously cleaned using **diskpart**.

In fear of losing all my important files, I copied 2 files from my email to my cleaned usb before using a tool to recover all my files.. I am not well versed of this things.

I downloaded *Minitool* and *Wondershare Photo Recovery* to recover my files but to no avail. Can anyone please help me.. the photos are my memories way back 10 years and I have no back up for it.. my files are important because it is my personal files used in my job..

Comment: More info about your computer would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Do not use the drive or try further amateur recovery... that will make matters worse.** Unplug it.
2. Since you state you *do not* have the required expertise, find a reliable data recovery service, but be prepared for expenses in the hundreds or thousands of euros (or dollars). It is possible that some files can be recovered, but using a disk partition tool makes recovery difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

A general overview.  In the abstract:

1. Don't panic, don't hurry, do no harm.
2. Back up an image of the USB drive device to your hard drive.  Once a good
   image is made, leave it alone, it's a safety.
3. Find out how bad the situation is using (lossless) compression.  Make a 2nd copy
   of the image.  Compress the image with some util.  If it doesn't
   compress very much that's good news, because it means the file
   data is probably still intact.  If it compresses a lot, (a 16GB
   disk image that had 10GB of pictures, but compresses to 1MB, let's say), its data is absolutely lost.
4. If the data is not lost, attempt recovery using whatever utils
   are available.  Repeat with fresh image copies as needed, or until
   futile.
5. If that fails, wait until somebody makes a better recovery util, or
   help sponsor such efforts.